# how to override vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml in magento 2

Tags: magento2

**how to override the color navigation swatch in magento 2 my code is in below but it is not working**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable" as="configurable" template="Mycustom_MultipleLayeredNavigation::layer/renderer.phtml" ifconfig="catalog/frontend/show_swatches_in_product_list" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: do  you find any solution for this, i m also facing a same one

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code, please put the file at:

```
app/design/frontend/{{Yourpackage}}/{{Yourtheme}}/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml
```

Or you can create custom module and follow below steps:

1. create a folder view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and put below code inside that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Your_module::path/to/yourtemplate.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Create the custom template with required customization as per the given path (its path/to/yourtemplate.phtml).

Comment: which xml file should i call to override color navigation in magento2

Comment: You can add this updates in custom module's catalog_product_view.xml file. I hope you are trying to update it at product view page.

Comment: If it is not exist already, then create new xml file at your/module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: i want to override in in product listing page

Comment: Then you need to create catalog_category_view.xml if it is not available.. @Hit's answer should work properly if you are following those steps properly..

Answer (score 0):

try below code from

> vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

create a new file into

> app/design/frontend/Customtheme/default/Magento_Swatches/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers"><!-- category.product.type.details.renderers means your core referenceBlock name-->
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mycustom_MultipleLayeredNavigation::layer/renderer.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

run command

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

OR

try with re-deploy to content

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: which xml file should i call to override color navigation in magento2

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override phtml files only then you can do with your custom theme as well.

1. Copy core file(renderer.phtml) from below path.

> vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml
>   in magento

2. Ex : Add above core file(rendered.phtml) to your custom theme

> app/design/frontend/Yourcompany/Yourtheme/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/layered/

3. Add your custom code in above file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create file under:

app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::product/layered/renderer.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Set your templae file at below location :

```
app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```